# Who is the 'certain brāhmaṇa of pious vows' in this conversation between Kṛṣṇa and Aśvatthāmā?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, ashwatthama

From [Sauptika Parva section 16](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10016.htm):

> Vaishampayana said, "Understanding that that weapon was thrown (into the wombs of the Pandava women) by Drona's son of sinful deeds, Hrishikesha, with a cheerful heart, said these words unto him: ‘**A certain brahmana of pious vows**, beholding Virata's daughter who is now daughter-in-law to Arjuna, while she was at Upaplavya, **said**, "**While the Kuru line will become extinct, a son will be born to thee.** This thy son for that reason, will be called by the name of Parikshit."
>
> The words of **that pious man** shall become true: the Pandavas shall have a son called Parikshit.
>
> Unto Govinda, that foremost one of the Satvata race, while he was saying these words, Drona's son, filled with wrath, replied, saying, ‘This, O Keshava, that thou sayest from thy partiality for the Pandavas, shall not happen. O thou of eyes like lotus-petals, my words cannot but be fulfilled. Uplifted by me, this weapon of mine shall fall on the foetus that is in the womb of Virata's daughter, upon that foetus which thou, O Krishna, art desirous of protecting.'

Who are ***certain brāhmaṇa of pious vows*** and ***that pious man*** in the above conversation between Kṛṣṇa and Aśvatthāmā? Does this brāhmaṇa have a name?

Comment: Well, this prophecy by a Brahmana isn't mentioned in the Virata Parva's description of the Pandavas' stay in Upaplavya, so I don't think there's any way to find out who this Brahmana is.